# Dot product of 3D vectors in webassembly

Tags: linear-algebra, webassembly, simd, dot-product

I want to calculate the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two vectors of 3 elements. I was looking on the [wasm vector instructions](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/instructions.html#vector-instructions) and there are only a single *dot* instruction:

```
i32x4.dot_i16x8_s
```

it's type is two `v128` as input and returns a `v128` according to [wasm specification](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/valid/instructions.html).

According to wikipedia:

> the dot product is an algebraic operation that takes two equal-length sequences of numbers (usually coordinate vectors), and returns a single number

but the name of the wasm instructions hints that it expects the two input vectors to be organized as `i32x4` and `i16x8`.

This does not really makes sense for me, since the input vectors are not in the same number of elements. In addition, I don't understand in what format the returning `v128` is organized, is is `i32x4` or `i16x8` or something else?

Also what is the correct wat to calculate the dot product of two 3D elements using 4D calculations, can I pad the vectors with `1`'s and perhaps manipulate the answer in some way?

If I would elaborate about a WAT code, I would guess something like:

```
(module
  (func $my_function (result i32)
    v128.const i32x4 1 3 -5 0
    v128.const i16x8 4 -2 -1 0 0 0 0 0
    i32x4.dot_i16x8_s
    i32x4.extract_lane 0
  )
)
```

the wikipedia article has an example:

```
dot([1 3 -5], [4 -2 -1]) returns 3
```

What is the proper way to do that using webassembly?

Comment: Looks like `i32x4.dot_i16x8_s` is meant to correspond to [`pmaddwd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddwd) (the naming may not be ideal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot product in wasm must be interpreted as i32x4 being the output, and i16x8 being the input. This indeed corresponds to Intel `pmaddwd` or pair-wise multiply add words into double words.
The intrinsic is also implementation specific, as -32768 **2 * 2 overflows int32_t.

To compute dot product of two 3-element vectors, one must just unroll it as `a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]`.

As suggested in the comments, it's often best to organise the data in a format, where one can compute 4 independent dot products vertically at a time.

```
struct vec3x4 {
     int32_t x[4];
     int32_t y[4];
     int32_t z[4];
};
```

Allocating a full v128 for just those three values might anyway help the JIT in optimising - even in the case that there's no dot product instructions on Intel (or Arm64) for integer values.

```
struct vec3_plus {
    int x,y,z,w{0};
};
```

The dot product between two of these values can anyway benefit from parallel execution of 3 real and 1 dummy multiplies, followed by either parallel or scalar reduction of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

As @harold commented and @Aki mentioned, the `i32x4.dot_i16x8_s` Webassembly instruction seem to correspond to [pmaddwd](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddwd).

I did find a better (compared to the specification) explanation of the wasm instruction in a [proposal document](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/main/proposals/simd/SIMD.md#integer-dot-product):

> **Integer dot product**
>
> `i32x4.dot_i16x8_s(a: v128, b: v128) -> v128`
>
> Lane-wise multiply signed 16-bit integers in the two input vectors and add adjacent pairs of the full 32-bit results.

Altough the instruction cannot be used directly as a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) operator for two vectors of 3 elements, as I wanted, it is still useful for such an implementation.

The description of `pmaddwd` is:

> Multiplies the individual signed words of the destination operand (first operand) by the corresponding signed words of the source operand (second operand), producing temporary signed, doubleword results. The adjacent double-word results are then summed and stored in the destination operand.

And this illustration is helpful:
[image: pmaddwd]

Since I want to use vectors of 3 elements, I can pad the input vectors with `0`'s, then extract the sums from the lanes, and finally do the remaining additions.

### Dot product implementation for 3D vectors

Considering the example in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

```
[1 3 -5] dot [4 -2 -1] = 3
```

I implemented a function that takes two 3 element numbers and calculate the *dot product* of those vectors:

```lisp
(module
  (func (export "calc_dot") (result i32)
    i32.const 1
    i32.const 3
    i32.const -5

    i32.const 4
    i32.const -2
    i32.const -1

    call $dot3
    return
  )

  (func $dot3 (param i32) (param i32) (param i32)
              (param i32) (param i32) (param i32) (result i32)
    (local v128)

    ;; create vector from first 3 params
    (i16x8.splat (i32.const 0))
    (i16x8.replace_lane 0 (local.get 0))
    (i16x8.replace_lane 1 (local.get 1))
    (i16x8.replace_lane 2 (local.get 2))

    ;; create vector from last 3 params
    (i16x8.splat (i32.const 0))
    (i16x8.replace_lane 0 (local.get 3))
    (i16x8.replace_lane 1 (local.get 4))
    (i16x8.replace_lane 2 (local.get 5))

    ;; integer dot product
    (local.set 6 (i32x4.dot_i16x8_s))

    (i32x4.extract_lane 0 (local.get 6))
    (i32x4.extract_lane 1 (local.get 6))
    i32.add

    return
  )
)
```

Comment: Does that do what you want though? Your i32 inputs will be truncated to i16. That may not be too bad but it's not really what I'd expect of a dot product between vectors of i32.

Comment: @harold thats the limitation, it is only wasm instruction support for `i16`.

Comment: It's the only WASM instruction that is *named* `dot` anyway, there are other ways to compute a dot product, such as taking a normal product (or even `extmul`) and then manually do a horizontal addition. Also this would all be easier if you had 4 vectors, with the x coordinates packed into one v128, the y's in another v128, and the z's in an v128, then you could just multiply and add and there'd be no weird horizontal SIMD needed

Comment: AFAIK wasm execution goes through at least one level of compilation to native instruction set (in common browsers and node.js); all the attempts to "optimise" in wasm might be either wasted effort or even counter-productive if the backend compiler is unable to translate your optimal sequence of byte code instructions to the optimal native instruction sequence.